# Opening and reading files

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

txt = open(filename)

print "Here's your file %r:" % filename
print txt.read()
```

When I run this code, using the name of a text file as the argument 'ex15_sample.txt' then it returns what is inside the text document.

But when I change the last line to:

```
print txt
```

Then it displays this:

```
<open file 'ex15_sample.txt', mode 'r' at 0x004A6230>
```

I'm not really sure what the difference is since the `txt` variable should be opening the file. I understand that the `read` command reads the file but in the docs it says the `open` one returns a file object and I'm not sure what this means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`open()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open) function will return a [`file` object](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects) which representation is indeed: `<open file 'ex15_sample.txt', mode 'r' at 0x004A6230>`.

In order the get the file's contents you need to [`read()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#file.read) it. That's why when you `print txt.read()` you get what you expect.

Comment: But what is the file object? What is the purpose of it?!

Comment: It's purpose is to wrap the operation regarding to files in the file object. For example, if the file you were opening would have 3GB would you want Python to automatically store it in a variable? It will be disastrously memory consuming, with the file object you can read in chunks and perform different operations without actually storing the whole file in the RAM.